# Rolling two dice alternatively. What is probability of winning?

Tags: probability

Tom and Paul roll 2 dice alternatively starting with Tom. Consider they use two fair 6-faced dice. The player who rolls 6 first wins. They continue to roll until one of them wins. Find probability that Tom wins.

I have listed out the total possible outcomes below:

{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (4,5), (4,6), (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5), (5,6), (6,1), (6,2), (6,3), (6,4), (6,5), (6,6)}

Here are all the possible outcomes of two dice rolls. And as one can see, only 5 of these comes out with a 6 first; so, I think the probability of Tom winning should be 5/36.

However, when I looked at the solution (This is a question from one midterm in one of previous semesters given at my school) says:

p is 5/36

$$P(Tom\, Wins)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }p(1-p)^{2k}=p\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }(1-p)^{2k}=$$
$$\frac{\frac{5}{36}}{1-\frac{31}{36}}=\frac{5}{5}$$

As one can see this answer is really rediculus! (Tom will win no matter what??)

I think that the key here is probably on the word "alternatively", but cannot figureout what has gone wrong here.

Comment: You’ve computed that sum incorrectly. Observe that the exponent is $2k$, not $k$, i.e., you’ve got a geometric series in $(1-p)^2$, not $1-p$.

Comment: I didn't come out with that answer. It is answer given by someone. I looked at it and was very confused.

Answer (score 3):

The probability that Tom wins on the first roll is $\frac16$. He wins on the third roll if and only if he first rolls something other than a $6$, then Paul rolls something other than a $6$, and then Tom rolls a $6$; the probability of this is $\frac56\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16$. In general, Tom wins on the $(2k+1)$-st roll if and only if the first none of the first $2k$ rolls is a $6$, and Tom rolls a $6$ on roll $2k+1$; this occurs with probability $\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^{2k}$. Thus, the probability that Tom wins is

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac16\left(\frac56\right)^{2k}&=\frac16\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac56\right)^{2k}\\
&=\frac16\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k\\
&=\frac16\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{25}{36}}\\
&=\frac6{11}\;.
\end{align*}$$

This is the formula in the solution that you read, with $p=\frac16$.

It should not be surprising that this is slightly more than $\frac12$: the fact that Tom goes first gives him an advantage, but it’s a small one, since the game is otherwise very symmetric.

One can also compute the desired probability without resort to infinite series. Let $p$ be the probability that Tom wins, so that Paul wins with probability $1-p$. On the other hand, the probability that Paul when Tom first rolls something other than a $6$ must be $p$, because at that point the game is effectively starting over with Paul as the first player. Thus, Paul wins with probability $\frac56p$, the probability that Tom rolls something other than a $6$ initially **and** Paul then rolls a $6$ before Tom does. In short, $1-p=\frac56p$, and solving for $p$ again yields $p=\frac6{11}$.

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer is good. I guess the solution given for this problem is probably wrong.

Comment: @AmosKu: You’re welcome.

Comment: I have given the question quite a bit of thought last night. I think the key is "alternatively". And whenever Tom rolls a 6, he wins. I think your answer is for the case where only one 6 face dice is rolled. I have edited my wording above, hoping to make the meaning of original question clearer.

Comment: @AmosKu: _Alternatively_ makes no sense here; I suspect that the intended word is _alternately_. That simply means that Tom rolls his die, then Paul rolls his, and so on. This is exactly the same problem as if they were using a single die and trading it back and forth.

Comment: Possible. But I just double checked the original question. The word is " Alternatively". There are other errors in the writing of the test as well. I guess you are right.

Comment: @AmosKu: Then the person who wrote the question used the wrong word; _alternatively_ simply makes no sense there.